# Issue selecting from Associative Array using a Table Collection Expression

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I seem to be having an issue when using a Table Collection Expression to select from an Associative Array (Note: I am using Oracle 12c, so this is allowed: [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12101.htm#NEWFT147))

Take the following "simple" example:

First, create a package which declares a record and the associative array:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE table_test
IS
  TYPE pt_DateSpan IS RECORD
  (
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE
  );

  TYPE pt_DateSpanTable IS TABLE OF pt_DateSpan INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
END;
/
```

Then, I wrote the following anonymous block to test the functionality:

```sql
DECLARE
  l_tTest table_test.pt_DateSpanTable;
  
  PROCEDURE lp_outputAArray (p_aaInput table_test.pt_DateSpanTable) IS
    l_nTableSize INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    --I know I can use p_aaInput.COUNT, but I want to select using TABLE() to show that the functionality "works"
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO l_nTableSize
    FROM TABLE(p_aaInput);
    dbms_output.put_line('Table Size: '||l_nTableSize);
  
    FOR i IN 1..p_aaInput.COUNT LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(i||': '||to_char(p_aaInput(i).StartDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')||' - '||to_char(p_aaInput(i).EndDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
    END LOOP;
  END lp_outputAArray;
BEGIN
  --ADD RECORD TO ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY
  SELECT to_date('01/01/2000', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), to_date('01/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_tTest
  FROM DUAL;
  
  lp_outputAArray(l_tTest);  
  
  --SELECT THE ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY INTO ITSELF
  SELECT t.StartDate, t.EndDate
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_tTest
  FROM TABLE(l_tTest) t;
  
  lp_outputAArray(l_tTest);
END;
/
```

This block produces the following output:

```
Table Size: 1
1: 01/01/2000 - 01/01/2010
Table Size: 0
```

My question is why is the second output not identical to the first?

Also, I realize that I don't need to use `BULK COLLECT` in most of this example, it is a simplified version of my actual code which does `SELECT` from actual tables.

My final goal was to use `UNION ALL` to allow me to append values to my Associative Array instead of replacing it when performing a series of `SELECT` statements.  Something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_tTest
  FROM (SELECT t.StartDate, t.EndDate
        FROM TABLE(l_tTest) t
        UNION ALL
        SELECT to_date('01/01/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), to_date('01/01/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        FROM DUAL);
```

I would appreciate any help you could provide.

Comment: It appears to be a bug with `BULK COLLECT INTO` when you use the same collection as you are selecting from. It works when you `BULK COLLECT INTO` a different associative array [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=067712429aaa159b676abade8630ea36).

Comment: @MT0 Thank you for your quick response.  That seems to work.  I guess I'll just use two Associative Arrays and switch back and forth.  Also, I didn't know DBFiddle worked with PL/SQL, that will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that when you use:

```sql
SELECT ...
BULK COLLECT INTO array
FROM   ...
```

Then the first thing that happens is that the `array` you `BULK COLLECT INTO` is re-initialised to an empty array.

Therefore, when you want to use it in the table collection expression it is already empty and no rows are generated.

---

Instead, you could use a non-associative array and use the `MULTISET` operators in PL/SQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE table_test
IS
  TYPE range IS RECORD
  (
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE
  );

  TYPE range_table IS TABLE OF range
                      --INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER
                      ;
END;
/

DECLARE
  l_ranges  table_test.range_table := table_test.range_table();
  l_ranges2 table_test.range_table := table_test.range_table();

  PROCEDURE output_ranges(
    range_array table_test.range_table
  )
  IS
    idx PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('Table Size: '||range_array.COUNT);
  
    idx := range_array.FIRST;
    LOOP
      EXIT WHEN idx IS NULL;
      dbms_output.put_line(
        idx||': '||range_array(idx).StartDate||' - '||range_array(idx).EndDate
      );
      idx := range_array.NEXT(idx);
    END LOOP;
  END output_ranges;
BEGIN
  l_ranges.EXTEND(2);
  l_ranges(1) := table_test.range(DATE '2000-01-01', DATE '2001-01-01');
  l_ranges(2) := table_test.range(DATE '2001-01-01', DATE '2002-01-01');

  l_ranges2.EXTEND(2);
  l_ranges2(1) := table_test.range(DATE '2002-01-01', DATE '2003-01-01');
  l_ranges2(2) := table_test.range(DATE '2003-01-01', DATE '2004-01-01');

  output_ranges(l_ranges);
  output_ranges(l_ranges2);
  
  l_ranges := l_ranges MULTISET UNION ALL l_ranges2;

  output_ranges(l_ranges);
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> Table Size: 2
> 1: 01-JAN-00 - 01-JAN-01
> 2: 01-JAN-01 - 01-JAN-02
> Table Size: 2
> 1: 01-JAN-02 - 01-JAN-03
> 2: 01-JAN-03 - 01-JAN-04
> Table Size: 4
> 1: 01-JAN-00 - 01-JAN-01
> 2: 01-JAN-01 - 01-JAN-02
> 3: 01-JAN-02 - 01-JAN-03
> 4: 01-JAN-03 - 01-JAN-04
> ```